# AJAX is not reloading the Page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datetime

I am tasked to use JavaScript and JSON to return and display the data on browser. I am very new to AJAX and I am having trouble getting AJAX fired by button click.The Main issue is getting AJAX fired up.

I am trying to load the data on the same screen every time an user enters a new data.

PHP Code:

```
<h2>Submit Recipes</h2>
<form id="addRecipes" name="addRecipes" action="Welcome.php"method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit Recipes</legend>
        <textarea id="recipesId" name="recipes" rows="6" cols="70"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="submitRecipes()"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<br/>
<table id="recipesTbl" border="1" >
    <tr>
        <th class="row-datetime" name="datetime">DateTime </th>
        <th class ="row-recipes" name="recipes">  Recipes </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ajax Code:

```
function submitRecipes() {

    var recipes = document.getElementById("recipesId").value;   
    if (recipes == null || recipes == "") {
        alert("Please enter the recipes");
        return false;
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {

             var text = request.responseText;
             var json = JSON.parse(text);

            var table = document.getElementById("recipesTbl");

            var newRow = table.insertRow(1);

            var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell.innerHTML = json.datetime;

            newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
            newCell.innerHTML = json.recipes;

        }
    }
    request.open("POST", "SubmitRecipes.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
    request.send("recipes=" + recipes);

    document.getElementById("recipesId").value = "";
}
```

PHP File Snippet:

```
<?php
$recipes= $_POST["recipes"];
date_default_timezone_get('UTC');
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

storeRecipes($recipes, $datetime);

echo ('{ "datetime" : "'. $datetime. '",'.
        '"recipes": "'.recipes .'"}');
?>
```

Comment: Whats your browser console say, can you see the request..? also your json in open to attack..

Comment: @JaromandaX  `'"recipes": "'.recipes .'"}` though its missing a `$` potential `{"recipes":"</script><script>alert('XSS')</script>"}`

Comment: ahh, I'm stupid :p

Comment: hi, I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Comment: because you're not sending JSON in PHP - check the developer tools networks tab to see what's coming back from your request

Comment: Hi, i am not getting it what do you mean by "not sending JSON in PHP"?

Answer (score 0):

The function `storeRecipes` does not exist. To make `JSON.parse` work, **single quotation mark (')** must be *outside* and **double quotation mark (")** must be *inside*.

For example :

```js
var string = '{"a": "1", "b": "2"}';
var res = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(res);
```

With

```
<?php

$recipes = $_POST["recipes"];
date_default_timezone_get('UTC');
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// storeRecipes($recipes, $datetime);

$data = '{"datetime": ' . '"' . $datetime . '",';
$data .= '"recipes": ' . '"' . $recipes . '"}';

echo $data;
?>
```

(and with the script file in the `<head>` section) it should work!

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer has helped you, please mark the it as useful and/or accept it. Thanks!